# Checking if a file exists in several directories

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting, find

I need a script that will look at files in a directory and see if it exists in one of several directories.

I need something like this:

```
for files in /downloads/ #may or may not be in a sub-directory
do
   print if file exists in /media/tv, /media/movie, or /media/music
done
```

the files will not be in the root of the directory.
I can't just search /media, because I don't want to search in cd-rom or videos.

I am using the latest version of Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 8):

You don't mention if you need to keep the files (perhaps removing duplicates?), hardlink them or anything else.

So, depending on your intention, the best solution would be to use one program like [rdfind](http://rdfind.pauldreik.se/) (not interactive), [fdupes](https://code.google.com/p/fdupes/) (more interactive, allowing you to choose which files to keep or not), [duff](http://duff.sourceforge.net/) (to only report the files that were duplicate) or many others.

If you want something fancier with a GUI that will let you choose what to keep via a point-and-click interface, then [fslint](http://www.pixelbeat.org/fslint/) (via its `fslint-gui` command) would be my recommended choice.

All of the above are available in Debian's repository and, by transition, I think that they are in Ubuntu's or Linux Mint's repositories, if that's what you are using.

Comment: The goal is to find files that i have downloaded, but have not yet copied to my media directory. Although finding duplicates will be a nice way to clean up my collection, its not what I'm looking to do in this script.

Comment: @andrew.vh, any of the utilities above would catch files with the same names, as they, more generally, will look for the contents of the files, not just their names, as you already noticed.

Answer (score 4):

This could be very slow if you traverse `/downloads` or `/media` for each file name. So traverse each hierarchy only once, store the list of file names, and then process the lists.

For simplicity, I assume that your file names don't contain any newlines.

```
find /downloads -type f | sed 's!^.*/\(.*\)$!\1/&!' |
  sort -t / -k1,1 >/tmp/downloads.find
find /media/tv /media/music /media/movie -type f |
  sed 's!^.*/\(.*\)$!\1/&!' |
  sort -t / -k1,1 >/tmp/media.find
```

At this point, the two `.find` files contain lists of file paths, with the name of the file prepended, sorted by file name. Join the files on the first `/`-separated field, and clean up the result a bit.

```
join -j 1 -t / /tmp/downloads.find /tmp/media.find |
  sed -e 's![^/]*/!!' -e 's![^/]*/! has the same name as !'
```

Comment: This is the `join` command that worked for me: `join -j 1 -t / /tmp/downloads.find /tmp/media.find | sed -e 's![^/]*/!!' -e 's!//! has the same name as /!'` (tested on two computers running SLES 10 and 11.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation in bash using brace expansion:

```
the_file=foo.mp3
for file in /downloads/media/{tv,movie,music}/"$the_file"; do 
   if [[ -e $file ]]; then
      printf '%s found in %s:\n' "$the_file" "${file%/*}"
   fi
done
```

Comment: As I understand it, `/media/` is not a subfolder of `/downloads/`

Comment: The original poster didn't mention it, but your method essentially only looks at the file names, not at the file contents.  Which is the original poster's intention is not clear, though.

Comment: Bernhard is correct, they are not in a subfolder of downloads.

Comment: also I didnt realize you could compare files based on contents. that would be nice as sometimes I would like to rename the files.

Answer (score 1):

This will list all files in downloads that are also in your specified /media subdirectories:

```sh
find /downloads -type f | while IFS= read -r file ; do
    bn=$(basename "$file")
    find /media/tv /media/movie /media/music -type f -name "$bn"
done
```

and this will just print whether the file has been found in one of those /media sub-directories or not.

```sh
find /downloads -type f | while IFS= read -r file ; do
    bn=$(basename "$file")

    count=$(find /media/tv /media/movie /media/music -type f -name "$bn" | wc -l)

    [ "$count" -gt 0 ] && printf "found %s\n" "$f"
done
```

If there are many files in /downloads, running `find` once for each file will be very slow.  That can be solved (if you are using GNU `find`) by building a regular expression containing all the filenames you want to search for and using GNU `find`'s `-regex` or `-iregex` options.

```sh
REGEXP="^.*/\("
find /downloads -type f | while IFS= read -r file ; do
    bn=$(basename "$file" | sed -e 's/\./\\./g')
    REGEXP="$REGEXP\|$bn"
done
REGEXP="$REGEXP\)$"

find /media/tv /media/movie /media/music -type f -iregex "$REGEXP"
```

And here's another version that doesn't use the shell built-in `read` so should be much faster:

```sh
REGEXP=$(find /downloads -type f | sed -e 's/^.*\/// ; s/\([]*\ .|[]\)/\\\1/g ; 
    s/$/\\|/' | tr -d '\n')
find /media/tv /media/movie /media/music -type f -iregex "^.*\($REGEXP\)$"
```

Both of these regexp versions are limited by the maximum line length of a shell command - too many files and they will fail.

---

NOTE: like most other answers here, these examples do not cope with filenames that have newlines (`\n`) in them.  Any other character, including space, is fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Enter file name"
read file
flag=0

for i in 'ls'
do
  if [ $i == $file ] ;then
    echo "File exist"
    flag=1
    break;
  fi
done

if [ $flag == 0 ] ;then
  echo "File not exist"
fi
```

Comment: That only checks in the _current_ directory...

Answer (score 0):

```
chk='/[m]edia'
for f in $chk/movies/file $chk/tv/file $chk/music/file
do  [ -z "${f##"$chk"*}" ] ||
    printf %s\\n "$f exists!"
done
```

You can glob against a known value and check its results for resolution.

Answer (score 0):

*How about:*

```
cd /sourcemp4folder
for i in *.mp4
 do
 a=$(find /destination/ -iname "$i" -print | wc -l)
 if [[ $a > 0 ]]; then echo "Skip "
 else echo "cp $i to /destination/"
 fi
 done
```